# Computer isn't resolved in domain

Tags: windows-10, networking, dns

Following situation:

- I have 2 (Dell) notebooks of different type but approx. same age
- Both run Windows 10 Pro, latest patch level
- Both are within a Windows Server 2016 domain
- One notebook is found and can be pinged by name (RemoteDesktop works)
- The other notebook is not found and can not be pinged by name (and RemoteDesktop does not work)

I did several investigations/trials:

- Compared Network settings
- Compared Firewall settings (incl. disabling the firewall)
- Quit/Rejoined domain (incl. deleting the lease o the domain controller)
- Checking that they are in the same domain group
- Reset ARP cache

Still: One notebook remains hidden. nslookup does only work for one of the notebooks. Please not that e.g. pinging and accessing remote desktop via IP address works! But since we have DHCP its not a good "solution".

I am running out of ideas what the problem could be. What else could I check to find out why one notebook is working properly and the others does not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Name resolution in an Active Directory domain uses regular DNS – each computer registers its own addresses by sending a DNS 'UPDATE' request to the DNS domain's master server (which is one of your AD domain controllers).

Directory OUs (and groups) are irrelevant; the actual AD domain join is slightly relevant to the extent that the computers use Kerberos to authenticate the updates they send, and your DCs/DNS servers are most likely set to "secure updates only" (which is good). But the actual name resolution doesn't go through AD.

(ARP cache is *very* irrelevant. The firewall rules would be relevant for mDNS/LLMNR using ".local" names, although the Windows Firewall already has built-in rules for those; however, they're not relevant for normal DNS, as it's the DC that is responding and not the machine itself.)

1. Run `ipconfig /all` and verify that the correct "domain suffix" is configured, both globally (should be set as part of the AD join) and perhaps per-interface (obtained from the DHCP lease). When you try to resolve "somename", the OS automatically appends this suffix and the actual lookup is done for "somename.ad.example.com", not just for "somename".
2. While you're looking at ipconfig, make sure both systems have correct DNS servers set. This is especially important if your AD domain is "internal" (using a made-up name instead of a real DNS domain) – *both* machines need to be able to query the domain name.

   Typically this means configuring the machines to use AD DCs as their DNS servers.

   (And if the machines are using the AD DCs as their DNS servers, then they should use *only* the AD DCs as their DNS servers – i.e. don't mix AD with 8.8.8.8 or whatever.)
3. On the missing host, run `nslookup -q=soa ad.example.com` (using your actual AD domain name of course) and make sure it receives a SOA response, and that the 2nd field points at a working AD DC (that's where the DNS updates will be sent).

   Then make sure you can `nslookup` that server's name; make sure you can ping it; and make sure it responds to DNS queries (e.g. `nslookup google.com dc01.ad.example.com`).
4. Open the DNS Server management console (`dnsmgmt.msc`) and connect to one of your AD domain controllers. Check whether both hosts have created themselves the correct DNS records.
5. On the missing host, run `ipconfig /registerdns` to cause it to re-send DNS updates. (You might want to install Wireshark and take a look at the packets being sent – do they go to the correct server? do they carry GSS-TSIG authentication data?)

   After doing this, open the Event Viewer on the host (`eventvwr.msc`) and look in the "Application" log for any events related to the DNS update.

   If they correctly reached your AD domain controller but were rejected, this should also be logged in the DC's event log (not sure which log exactly).
6. If the update appears to have succeeded, re-check using DNS Server console. If the records are there, test with `nslookup`, from both machines.

Comment: Thank you very much!That actually solved it for me. In the DNS Server management console (dnsmgmt.msc) I found another (old) entry with a different name that was pointing to the same IP. After deleting this entry (and restarting the host PC just to make sure) it was accessible by name. I am not sure where this entry came from - probably the host was registered in previous times w/o my knowledge. That also explains why I could access it via IP and why nslookup was not working.

Comment: Did the PC restart make it re-register itself with the correct address this time? (If it did, that's good. If not, then it might be that you're currently relying on LLMNR / mDNS / NetBIOS for intra-subnet name resolution...)

Comment: Yes, it did re-register with the proper name/address then. Basically I found out the cuplrit by comparing with other hosts that were working properly. But you are right: You better double-check this! Thanks!